# VB.NET StreamReader cant encode French Character Accents

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, io, encode, streamreader

Working on Reading a simple .DAT file by streamReader

```
rdr = New System.IO.StreamReader(Path&FileName, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
StrLine = rdr.ReadLine()
```

and then using **SubString** function to split **StrLine.SubString(1,10)** for database insert operation.

Turns out my .DAT file has proper french accent characters which getting screwed before I could insert them into database.

For Example, **'15 fév. 2012'** becomes **'10 f?v. 2012'** And **'27-Aug-2012'** becomes **'27 ao?t. 2012'**

First I thought its database issue so I changed all columns to support nvarchar but now it looks like I am probably not using right encoding while reading the file or something totally not aware of. Could anyone direct me to right path please? I dont understand encode/decode a great deal ..

Thanks

Comment: How are you viewing the text when it shows the '?', I could just be whatever viewer you are using doesn't support displaying the character. To ensure its using the correct encoding, try writing the data to a temp file and then comparing the to files using the same text editor.

Comment: Before any kind of processing I checked up the file and the french characters are all showing fine. It just when I am reading the file using StreamReader they are producing garbage. I did put a break point to make sure there is no more processing taking in place in between.